# My query is about rewriting url

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite my URL from

```
https://abc.com/category/computers/21        (this may be any number)
```

To:

```
https://abc.com/category/computers
```

I have tried some methods like given below but it is not working

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/$ interna.php?name_of_Category=$1&category_number [NC,L]
```

please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out this online tool for creating your .htaccess files: http://www.htaccessredirect.net/

which gives you:

```
//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 https://abc.com/category/computers/(.*) https://abc.com/category/computers/
```

Hopes this helps. Also, can I ask why you want to re-direct all the pages to the main directory?